# jquery simple modal ie8 height is not working

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I am having a problem with simple modal 1.4.3 opening in ie8. It opens with the correct width but it appears to have no height. It is specified in my js (comingsoon2013). I have looked on this site and github but no one has answered a similar question. The site is: http://www.greatgulf.com. The link is in the footer, it is the "Sign Up Now" button.

I am using jquery 1.8.3 also.

Cheers!

Comment: please post your code here

Comment: Did you check the console for error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Either the plugin isn't calculating properly or you have an inline style that shouldn't be there. (Update: after looking at the modal in Firefox, I'd surmise the former. It may be that your modal content isn't present early enough for the plugin to do its math.) Try this:

```
simplemodal-container {height: auto !important}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to select an answer. Credit for effort is what makes SO work well.